# How to pass a dict parameter from Python to Frida RPC JavaScript function?

Tags: rpc, frida

I want to pass dict to RPC, here is my agent.js:

```
rpc.exports = {
    signrequesturlwithparameters: function (param_dict,secret,signMethod) { 
    var result=ObjC.classes.GSNetworkUtils.signRequestUrlWithParameters_secret_signMethod_(param_dict,secret,signMethod);
    return String(ObjC.classes.NSString.stringWithString_(result));
    }
};
```

RPC invoke example;

```
script.load()
signrequesturlwithparameters= getattr(script.exports, 'signrequesturlwithparameters')
_dict={"imsi":"46001","device_model":"iPhone7,2"}
secret="93AA27467E8"; 
signMethod="md5";
a=signrequesturlwithparameters(_dict,secret,signMethod)
print(a)
```

There is an error, can I pass a dict from Python to JavaSript RPC function? How should I modify the Python or JavaScript code to make it work?

Update:
I tried JSON.parse,but it seems frida's javascript cannot use `JSON`.Another issue is when I want to pass a variable parameter dict to `a=signrequesturlwithparameters(_dict,secret,signMethod)`,how should I use `setObject_forKey_("key1","value1")`? I think I should resolve the variable parameter dict in frida javascript,then I tried to pass `str(dict)` from python to frida javascript and  tried to resolve the string dict to dict in frida javascript with `ObjC.classes.NSJSONSerialization`,more details is [here](https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/985),but still fail,can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `json.dumps` in py side & `JSON.parse` in JS side, but I think your issue is @ `signRequestUrlWithParameters_secret_signMethod_` I do not think it expecting JSON but `NSDictionary` or something similar.

```js
var NSDict = ObjC.classes.NSMutableDictionary.alloc().init();   
NSDict.setObject_forKey_("key1", "value1");     
NSDict.setObject_forKey_("key2", "value2");
signRequestUrlWithParameters_secret_signMethod_(NSDict, ...);
```